# Getting Number of Occurrences of String in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am analyzing a website that returns text (JSON array), which I'm using HTTP Request element for. What I'm trying to do is check the number of times a string appears in the response, for example a field called "itemname". So I have added a Regular Expression Extractor, put `ItemNameVar` as the Reference Name, `^itemname$` as the Regular Expression, `$1$` for the Template, `-1` for Match No, and "NOT FOUND" for Default Value. I've also added an If Controller, which says `"${ItemNameVar_matchNr}" == "1"`, because I expect it to occur only one time. However, it never fails if I set it to a different number. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Showing a piece of code would probably be clearer that explaining it.

Comment: Is there maybe a Regex expression I can use for this? For example, if I want to find the EXACT number of times "hello" occurs in a whole string, could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like to be an issue with your regular expression.

I would suggest using [Beanshell Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) instead of Regular Expression Extractor as JSON structures aren't very handy to parse with regexes.

Reference Beanshell code will look as follows:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

int matches = StringUtils.countMatches(new String(data), "itemname");
vars.put("ItemNameVar_matchNr", String.valueOf(matches));
```

Explanation:

- **First line** - import necessary helper class
- **Second line** - `data` is a short-hand for byte-array representation of Sampler response. Method `countMatches` counts number of occurrences of `itemname` criteria in string representation of response data. Result is saved as `matches` integer variable
- **Third line** - value of `matches` is saved as JMeter Variable called `ItemNameVar_matchNr`

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more detailed explanation of Beanshell scripting in JMeter and small Beanshell cookbook containing JMeter API usage examples.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are following is absolutely correct.

Please check your Jmeter script. Make sure the next request you are trying to execute after
**IF Controller** is branch or within **Controller**

[Jmeter IF Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQRNT.jpg)

Hope this will help.